# Best way to count a distinct row grouped by a different row?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, count, group

DB is BigQuery, but it's very similar to most DB's, and I would imagine this answer will be universal.

**The Table**

```
user_id | date | category_id 
----------------------------
1       | xx   | 10
2       | xx   | 10
2       | xx   | 10
3       | xx   | 10
3       | xx   | 10
3       | xx   | 10
1       | xx   | 11
2       | xx   | 12
```

I would like to get a count of **distinct user_id's** per category_id

So the answer would produce :

```
category_id | distinct_user_count
---------------------------------
10          | 3
11          | 1
12          | 1
```

My apologies ahead of time if this has been asked before.

I should add that both of these SQL queries return the same result :

```
SELECT 
  category_id,
  count(distinct user_id)
FROM t
group by category_id
```

```
SELECT 
  category_id,
  count(user_id) over(partition by category_id)
FROM t
group by category_id, user_id
```

Produces unexpected results :

```
category_id | distinct_user_count
---------------------------------
10          | 1
11          | 1
12          | 1
```

Comment: And what does `SELECT * FROM <table>` return?

Comment: @Alexey The answer to that would be my first example under `The Table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
select  distinct count(user_id) over(partition by category_id) as "users_per_id", 
  category_id
from the_table
group by category_id, user_id
```

Comment: Was my first guess as well, but I get the results I added to my question above.. perhaps it's a BigQuery thiing?

Comment: maybe, look at this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=513f37ffa42aef72d0c658c1286458e0). it works well!

Comment: Unfortunately, BigQuery for some torturous reason doesn't perform the same as Postgresql. But I agree with you, this should definitely have worked.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution.

```
select category_id
      ,count(distinct user_id) as distinct_user_count
from t
group by category_id
```

| category_id | distinct_user_count |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 3 |
| 11 | 1 |
| 12 | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=66554ee74adcd813e89cddebe96106eb)

Comment: Maybe its a BigQuery issue as this was my first answer as well. I updated my answer above to show what results this would bring.

Comment: That unfortunately is not a BigQuery method

Comment: I'm signing up. give me 10m and I'll post the answer.

Comment: I checked it in BigQuery and it works the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query

```
SELECT 
    category_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS distinct_user_count
FROM t
GROUP BY category_id
```

Comment: Maybe its a BigQuery issue as this was my first answer as well. I updated my answer above to show what results this would bring.

Comment: Then you can try `SELECT category_id, EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(user_id) AS distinct_user_count
FROM t
GROUP BY category_id`

Comment: Unfortunately `EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT` is not a BigQuery method